# how do I get my selected list back with the selected item (asp.net mvc 2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, selectlist

I try to make a view in ASP.NEt mvc 2 with a selectList.

I fill up the selectlist languages from my model (regDom)

listLangModel is a list of languages I retrieve from the database.

> regDom.Languages = from l in listLangModel
>
> ```
>                select new SelectListItem
>                      {
>                         Text = l.Name,
>                         Value = l.ID
>                      };
> ```

In my view I have this

> ```
>         <div class="editor-label">
>             <%: Html.LabelFor(model =>> model.Languages) %>
>         </div>
>         <div class="editor-field">
>             <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model =>  model.Languages, Model.Languages) %>
>             <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Languages) %>
>         </div>
> ```

When I run, the languages are in the dropdownlist on my page.
But when I post it back to my server, the model doesn't contain the languages anymore.
And I can't check which language is selected on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can select only a single language from the drop down list, so you cannot expect it to populate the `Languages` property of your model which is a collection.

Add a property to hold the selected language in your model:

```
public string SelectedLanguage { get; set; }
```

and then bind the drop down list to this property:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLanguage, Model.Languages) %>
```

Comment: Thank you, now can I see which language is chosen.

But can I pass also my languages back. In case there is some input that is not valid (because of business rules), I can give back my form with all the languages?

Comment: Yes, you pass the model to the view (`return View(model)`) which has the `Languages` property containing all the languages allowing you to rebind the drop down list.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. 
But I get this error now: 

The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedLanguage' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

And when I debug, my languages variable of my object is empty when it comes back
.

Comment: Maybe for safety reasons it's better i refill my dropdownlist with the correct data before I return it back to the user.